# directive for array without using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Once again I stumbled on slow performance of `ng-repeat` and can't figure how to build a directive that will render an array of elements without utilizing `ng-repeat` anywhere (even in the template)

So, how do you guys do that?

Even if I iterate through the array, using template for every single element:

```
.directive('foo', function($parse, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
          scope: { items: '=myarray' },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs){
                 var tmplt = '<div> {{name}} </div>';
                 scope.items.forEach(function(){
                     element.append(tmplt(scope)); 
                     // now I'd like to have a scope of that element, 
                     // and pass it into the template, and use properties related 
                     // only to that element
                     // but I don't know how to get a scope for a child element
                  });

             scope.$watch(attrs.myarray, function(value) { console.log('something change'); })

            }
        }});
```

If I choose to have a single template for all the elements, then again I have no choice but to use `ng-repeat` in it and it will create ngRepeatWatchers and everything gets slow down again.

Comment: Each {{name}} will set up a $watch.  I don't see how this will be much faster than ng-repeat, especially considering you'd also like a separate scope for each item.  Does the array need to dynamically change?  Can you paginate your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I agree with @Mark, but here is dirty solution for your question:

http://plnkr.co/edit/wxM8mSoNsRGXBJUao5Xb?p=preview

The idea is to create isolated child scopes:

```
              scope.items.forEach(function(item){                     
                 var childScope = scope.$new(true);                     
                 angular.extend(childScope, item);
                 element.append($compile(tmplt)(childScope)); 
              });
```

And do not forget to delete those child scopes unpon each refresh.

and sill this solution needed to be benchmarked to see is it faster and how much comparing to ngRepeat.